# Recyclerview with set visibility

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a expense request kind of thing for my admin app. What i want to achieve is when the user clicks the approve button, the text on it should get changed to Approved and reject button should disappear and vice versa. 
I am unable to achieve this, I have tried everything but getting even weirder outputs with each attempt to fix this. Please attach a reason with your changes as it would help me. Thanks

This is my code

```
package com.emlocks.timeaccess;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Expenses extends AppCompatActivity {

    NetworkController networkController;

    Bundle ss;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    List<ExpenseP> expensep = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView rvRegs;
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();


    public static final String TAG = "Expenses";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expenses);

        ss = savedInstanceState;
        networkController = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(NetworkController.class);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.prefs), MODE_PRIVATE);
        rvRegs = findViewById(R.id.rvExpense);


        networkController = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(NetworkController.class);

        networkController.getexpense("Bearer " + prefs.getString("token", null), prefs.getString("email", null)).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

                if (response.code() == 200) {

                    JsonArray array = response.body().getAsJsonArray("data");
                    System.out.println(array);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + array);
                    for (JsonElement j :
                            array) {
                        expensep.add(gson.fromJson(j, ExpenseP.class));


                    }

                    rvRegs.setAdapter(new ExpenseAdapter());
                    rvRegs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Expenses.this));

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Unsuccessful" + response.errorBody());
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getStackTrace());
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });
    }

         class ExpenseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpenseAdapter.VH> {


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return new VH(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_expense, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final VH vh, int i) {

            final ExpenseP ex = expensep.get(i);
            vh.etFN.setText(ex.getUserId().split("-")[1]);
            vh.etnm.setText(ex.getDate());
            vh.etnm1.setText(ex.getAmount());
            vh.leaves.setText(ex.getRemark());
            vh.u_name.setText(ex.getName());
            vh.u_department.setText(ex.getDepName());


            if (ex.getStatus() == null) {

                View.OnClickListener approveRejectClickListner = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int status = 0;
                        switch (v.getId()) {
                            case R.id.btnApprove:
                                status = 1;
                              vh.btnReject.setEnabled(true);
                                break;
                            case R.id.btnReject:
                                status = 0;
                               vh.btnApprove.setEnabled(true);
                                break;


                        }


                        JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
                        body.add("expense_id", new JsonPrimitive(ex.getExpenseId()));
                        body.add("status", new JsonPrimitive(status));
                        body.add("user_id", new JsonPrimitive(ex.getUserId()));


                        networkController.patchexpense("Bearer " + prefs.getString("token", null), prefs.getString("email", null), body).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                                if (response.code() == 200) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Expenses.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

                            }
                        });


                        if(vh.btnApprove.isPressed()==true)
                        {
                            vh.btnApprove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        else if (vh.btnReject.isPressed()==true){
                            vh.btnReject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                };
                vh.btnApprove.setOnClickListener(approveRejectClickListner);
                vh.btnReject.setOnClickListener(approveRejectClickListner);
            }

            else
            if (ex.getStatus() != 1) {
                vh.btnReject.setText("Rejected");
               vh.btnApprove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            } else {
               vh.btnApprove.setText("Approved");
               vh.btnReject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           }




        }





        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return expensep.size();
        }


        class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView etFN, etnm, etnm1, leaves,u_name,u_department;
            Button btnApprove, btnReject;

            public VH(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                etFN = itemView.findViewById(R.id.U_code);
                etnm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                etnm1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
                leaves = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
                u_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.U_name);
                u_department=itemView.findViewById(R.id.U_dep);

                btnApprove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnApprove);
                btnReject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnReject);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do this would be to utilize multiple ViewHolders and corresponding view types.

When a user approves an item, you handle that approval click by updating the item in question, and then utilizing `notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())` to tell the Adapter that the item has changed.

You can override `getItemViewType` and have it return a layout depending on it's state.  For example:

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    // Protected common views, like name, etc.

    BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // set up common views
    }

    public final void bindTo(ExpenseP expense) {
        // set up common views
        onBind(expense);
    }

    protected abstract void onBind(ExpenseP expense);
}

class AcceptedExpenseViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {
    // Protected accepted-only views...

    BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // set up accepted-only views...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind(ExpenseP expense) {
        // bind accepted-only views...
    }
}

// Another class for RejectedExpenseViewHolder
// Another class for DefaultExpenseViewHolder (neither accepted or rejected)
```

Then, define a layout for each. Android IDs don't have to be globally unique.  We can leverage this by utilizing the same id for common fields.  For example, where we want the name to go is always `R.id.expense_name` or whatever.

- accepted_expense_item.xml
- rejected_expense_item.xml
- default_expense_item.xml

Each of these layouts will have a unique identifier, which we can utilize as the ViewType inside of getItemViewType and later in onCreateViewHolder, instead of specifying our own:

```
int getItemViewType(position) {
    ExpenseP item = data.get(position);
    if (item.getStatus() == null) return R.layout.default_expense_item;
    // ... etc.
}

BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(...) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    switch (viewType) {
    case R.layout.accepted_expense_item:
        return new AcceptedExpenseViewHolder(itemView)
    // etc.
    }
}
```

If you want to propagate clicks to update item state, you'd pass in some kind of listener to your ViewHolder, and update state appropriately when it's called.  Then you can notify your adapter that a state change occurred.  For example:

```
interface DefaultListener {
    void onAccepted(int position);
    void onRejected(int position);
}

class DefaultExpenseViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {
    // Protected default-only views...

    BaseViewHolder(View itemView, DefaultListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        Button accepted = findViewById(R.id.accepted);
        accepted.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onAccepted(getAdapterPosition()));
    }

    //...
}
```

This will propagate it up to wherever Listener is defined. For example, in the adapter's onCreateViewHolder you could have:

```
switch (viewType) {
    case R.layout.accepted_expense_item:
        return new AcceptedExpenseViewHolder(itemView, this)
    }
```

And have Adapter implement the listener.  You could then, when invoked, update the status appropriately and then notify the adapter that a change happened.

For example:

```
void onAccepted(int position) {
    ExpenseP item = data.get(position);
    networkControllerStuff.accept(item, response -> {
        // Check status, and update appropriately.
        // Remember to replace the item in data with an updated item.
        // And then:
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    })
}
```

TL;DR There's more things here I can think to handle, but the general approach I'm trying to get across here is to use multiple viewtypes to your advantage here, instead of trying to manipulate some global view.

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to android and couldnt actually get the most out of your answer